# Loading class from JAR fails when using the JNI in 64-bit C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm trying to load a class contained within a JAR file using the JNI on 64-bit C++ using V2017. I'm able to instantiate a JVM, but the JNI doesn't seem to be able to find the class.

I've tried setting the class path to the directory containing the JAR that contains the class I'm looking for, as well as setting it to the full path of the JAR but this doesn't work either, so would be grateful for any advice.

```
int main()
{
   JavaVM *jvm;   /* denotes a Java VM */
   JNIEnv *env;  /* pointer to native method interface */
   JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 8 VM initialization arguments */
   JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];
   options[0].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=C:\\AP\\lib\\myjar.jar";

   HINSTANCE hinstLib;
   std::string result = DetectJavaVM();
   hinstLib = LoadLibrary(result.data());

   if (hinstLib == 0)
   {
      printf("Error");
   }

   if (hinstLib != NULL)
   {
      typedef jint(JNICALL *PtrCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);
      typedef jint(JNICALL *PtrGetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs)(void *);

      PtrGetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs ptrGetDefaultArgs = (PtrGetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs");
      ptrGetDefaultArgs(&vm_args);
      vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
      vm_args.options = options;
      vm_args.nOptions = 1;
      vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

      PtrCreateJavaVM ptrCreateJavaVM = (PtrCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

      int res = ptrCreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

      jclass cls = env->FindClass("org/mypackage/myclass");

      jmethodID mid;

      if (cls != 0)
      {
         mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "intMethod", "(I)I");

      }

  }
```

}

Comment: What are the exact error messages?

Comment: I don't get any errors, the value of cls is null.

Comment: Do you *really* have a class called `myclass` (with that exact case)?

Comment: Nope, that's just for the purposes of that code example